# Horizon v2.0.0 config with Captive Core for pubnet is any example?

Tags: horizon, stellar.toml

I need setup a node for pubnet(mainnet) network watching node

https://github.com/stellar/go/blob/master/services/horizon/internal/docs/captive_core.md#configure-captive-core

is only testnet config and private network config,is any mainnet config example?

old version for stellar:

https://github.com/stellar/packages/blob/master/docs/stellar-core_pubnet_watcher.cfg

Answer (score 1):

This example public configuration should help you. https://github.com/stellar/go/blob/master/services/horizon/docker/captive-core-pubnet.cfg